# How to generate random number between any four numbers in javascript?

Tags: javascript

How to generate random number between any four numbers???
For example, I have these four numbers: 1,3,7,9 and the random number I want must be one of these numbers.
Can anyone please tell me how to do it in JavaScript???

Comment: You don't even tried, make a google search pls, this kind of question are in general deleted. Next time try getting the tour (the link for help is just in the top of the screen) to learn what you can ask and how to ask

Answer (score 0):

```
var array = [1,3,7,9];
var randInt = array[Math.floor(Math.random()*array.length)];
```

`Math.floor(Math.random()*array.length)` will generate a random integer between 0 and array.length-1. You can use this as an index to choose a random element from the array:

```
array[Math.floor(Math.random()*array.length)]
```

Comment: Some explanation of how or why this works would be a great addition to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Create an array and choose a random position in that array:

```js
var numbers = [1,3,7,9];

function show_number() {
  var i = Math.round(Math.random() * (numbers.length-1));
  alert(numbers[i]);
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript:show_number();">Show number</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

var arrNumbers = [1, 3, 7, 9];

// get random key
var randomKey = getRandomInt(0, arrNumbers.length-1);

// get random number
alert(arrNumbers[randomKey]);
```

Check the demo fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/manzapanza/3s1k2ykr/